Updated 'connectTimeout' & 'readTimeout' in karate-config.js file & in Background section of feature file not working & takes default 30000ms only
I have written the following code to update default timeout in karate framework in config and feature file but still it took default time of 30sec instead updated time of 80sec. Please help.
**karate-config.js file:** 
    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 80000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 80000);

**Background section of feature file:**
Background:
    * url mywebsiteURL
    * configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 10000 }

**Result:**
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Error {
  message='Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "file:///opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/test/java/test-mysite-iframe.html", waiting until "load"
============================================================
  name='TimeoutError
  stack='TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "file:///opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/test/java/test-mysite-iframe.html", waiting until "load


maybe your dependencies are wrong. best option is for you to debug locally. or replicate the problem for others to look at

@PeterThomas, I am using karate-core & katrate-junit4 version 1.3.1 with java 1.8.0_362 & Maven 3.6.3. All the UI & API automated tests are running successfully using karate framework. So, dependencies wise it seems no issue.
Can you tell me how to debug it locally as I am calling above 'test-mysite-iframe.html' file from java class and opened chrome browser using playwright java library. This java class method I am calling from feature file with karate framework.

is this timeout for UI tests ? then refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver (search for httpConfig) else I can't suggest anything, read other answers maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+readTimeout

@PeterThomas, this has been resolved. Actually, with karate I am launching browser using playwright java library as I need to intercept the XHR request and grab the json response. So, as playwright comes here, I need to increase default timeout of playwright from 30 sec to more than 60 sec instead of increasing the timeout of karate. In playwright I got java method of increase in default time out.
